# Webservice invocation in BPEL with abstract return type

Tags: web-services, inheritance, bpel

Is it possible to invoke in BPEL a webservice that has a return type an abstract class and at runtime returns any of the derived types?
E.g. if the return type is an order status which has a status field, and its subclasses having  specific fields for different cases (valid order, invalid order, etc.).
The problem is that at invocation you have to specify an output variable that should be of this abstract type and subtype specific data couldn't be stored in a single type.
So far I have thought only of defining a data type that should accommodate all possible cases by having defined all fields of all derived classes.
Is there a better approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible, but may depend on the BPEL engine you are using.
I can recall that I have done similar processes in Apache ODE and WSO2 BPS.

If your BPEL engine does not support this, may be you can create several variables with the absolute types and use them appropriately in the invocations.

HTH